# Leave superscript mode in Mac Grapher

Tags: mac, keyboard, shortcut, keybindings, grapher

Mac Grapher has is a keyboard shortcut for entering superscripts: use the `^` key.  For instance, you can type `x^2` to get the expression *x*<sup>2</sup>.

Once I've entered superscript mode, how do I leave superscript mode?  For instance, if I want to enter in the expression *x*<sup>2</sup> + 3, what do I type?  If I type the characters `x^2 + 3` on the keyboard, I get the expression *x*<sup>2 + 3</sup>, which is not what I wanted.

I couldn't find any description of this in the help pages for Grapher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use down arrow <kbd>↓</kbd> or right arrow <kbd>→</kbd> (on navigation keys ⬌⬍) to leave superscript mode.